# How to connect TV to Ethernet via daisy chained Ethernet jacks?

Tags: ethernet

We built our home 3 years ago and added most all of the Ethernet jacks to locations where we thought they would be needed for TVs and access points. Over the fireplace in the family room we have a mounted TV connected to the internet via Wi-Fi. Although fine I would like to utilize the ethernet port behind the TV for wired connection.

The dilemma is I believe the install company daisy chained the HDMI/Ethernet jack behind the TV to a corresponding HDMI/Ethernet jack located on the lower third of the wall some 8 feet away to hide wires from cable boxes, receivers, Blu-ray etc. We stream content only so we do not have a cable box or player of any kind that utilizes the jack near on the wall near the floor.

How can I utilize the HDMI/Ethernet jack behind the TV to connect to the internet if the two jacks are daisy chained?

Installer line items.

> [image: Installer line items]

Jack located on wall near floor.

> [image: Screenshot.]

Jack located behind TV.

> [image: Screenshot.]

Comment: Actually if my memory serves daisy chained Ethernet should work fine if plugs are done correctly. That's how Ethernet hubs worked before switches became cheap enough to make hubs obsolete. Ethernet has built-in mechanisms to deal with shared medium. It's not ideal, but it's something.

Comment: So basically what you’re saying is that you have a connection from the TV to somewhere else in the same room. Do you have other Ethernet jacks in the room that you know are connected to the general in-house network?

Comment: I've added the invoice line items from the installer and a couple of photos. I think what I've gathered from the previous comments is that the HDMI and Cable jacks are likely daisy chained but ethernet ports not. The photo of the jack away from the TV does have an AP plugged in and operating. I have taken a spare AP and tried the remaining Cat6 cables in the switch located in the basement to no avail. Could it be possible that after reading the installer notes that the Cat6 jack behind the TV is not installed with corresponding Cat6 cable to the basement control center?

Comment: @gronostaj: Hubs did replicate the signal across all outputs without looking at it much, but they still had to (at the very minimum) link each port's Tx pair to all other ports' Rx pairs, I think it was somewhat more complex than just daisy-chaining all Tx pairs and all Rx pairs into one bundle – at least looking at the schematics of a [passive "hub"](https://www.eeweb.com/building-a-passive-ethernet-hub/), even a 3-way connection is a bit more complex than that.

Comment: @Tpete does the second jack away from the TV also allow the AP to connect? It would be strange to only send one of those jacks down to the basement. To be sure, you could try using a cable tester on each of the basement cables. Or just plug something into the TV's jack, and check for link-lights on the switch side

Comment: @Cpt I took the plate off the jack near the floor and there was one gray & one green Cat6 that I assume run down to the control panel. I cannot access the plate behind the TV without taking it off. This is turning into a real PIA - I hate to order tester for this one-time use.

Comment: @Tpete Is the TV currently connected and inaccessible then, or can you can plug into the TV's jack with something like a laptop? You should be able to see pretty easily whether the basement switch is connected on the other end.

Comment: I didn't mean to take the other plate apart - I was just curious if both jacks actually work/connect to the switch. If they were daisy-chained like you suspected, then the connected jack near the floor probably wouldn't work either

Comment: @Cpt.Whale the spare AP will not connect with the switch via the open Cat6 jack and any of the open/unused cat6 wires in the control center. Any additional thoughts if the two jacks (floor & behind TV) are tethered together?

Comment: @Tpete to see if they're connected to each other, just plug something into both ends. For example, if the TV is on and plugged into the tv jack, and you have a laptop plugged into the floor jack, then you should see ethernet link-lights, even if there isn't a real network there. It should also *not* light up if the TV is disconnected. I don't know if your APs have lights or PoE, but they might work to test too

Comment: If they are tethered together, then ideally you could have the installer fix it. Otherwise you can either sacrifice the floor jacks and connect TV > floor1 > floor2 > basement, or get a cheap switch and set it up nearby to connect floor1, floor2, and your AP together

Comment: Yup called the rep yesterday and he confirmed the floor jack and mantle jack are tethered ugh. He explained the small switch route but since we are a streaming only house and I am not using the tethered components (Coax, HDMI & Cat6) for their intended use, I am going to have an electrician untether the Cat6 port on the mantle to run down to the basement switch directly. Appreciate everyone's thoughts and comments